# ASP.NET and C# - Query with Guid as parameter throws exception

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, exception, guid

For context, I'm developing a booking website. One of the features is the ability of the logged in user being able to see his past reservations. For this, I'm populating a DataList with the help of a TableAdapter.

To accomplish this, I'm grabbing the ID of the user by doing so:

`var currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
 Guid userID = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;`

And then, passing that Guid to the query:

```
viagem = new viagemTableAdapter();
viagem.GetDataByCliente(userID);
```

Here is the DataSet:
[image]

And the query on GetDataByCliente is as follows:

```
SELECT        id, destino, nrAdultos, nrCriancas, checkin, checkout, hotel, extra_transpHotel, extra_transpAerop, extra_almoco, extra_jantar, extra_espetaculo, preco
FROM            viagem
WHERE        (idCliente = @idCliente)
```

I tried converting the ProviderUserKey to String for ease, however I can't pass it to the query due to idCliente being an UniqueIdentifier on the table.

On theory, this should be working. The problem is, everytime I try to access the page, this exception is thrown:

[image]

I can't explain it, no matter what. Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `GetDataByCliente` method?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have said the GetDataByCliente code is the query itself. It's a DataSet method

Comment: Yeah, but where is the code for the method implementation..

Comment: What is the database?
Is there an inner exception to give you more of a clue?

Comment: @Hackerman, looks like OP is using typed dataset and thus it's not a actual method iplementation

Comment: Exacly there is no method implementation as far as I know (it's a university project). I updated the post with the DataSet tables, I hope it'll make you understand it better

Comment: How about `viagem.GetDataByCliente("'" + userID.ToString()+ "'");`

Comment: @Hackerman That would mean passing a string to the query, which I can't due to idCliente being UniqueIdentifier. That field is UniqueIdentifier because it's referencing aspnet_Users.UserId

Comment: Just for testing purposes...did you try it?

Comment: I did and it didn't work. Gave me an error that said something along the lines of "can't convert String to Guid"

Comment: And when you set the type from guid to string in the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this to get GUID as a string, and than pass as a string param to method:

```
string userID= Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey.ToString();

//For currently logged in user you could use without passing the User.Identity.Name;

string userID= Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();

viagem = new viagemTableAdapter();
viagem.GetDataByCliente(userID);
```